# How to get the html element id if user pressed enter inside textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, keypress

There is much more code, but I will only show one function here:

```
$(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // how to check if a user pressed enter inside a specific
        // textarea box 
    }
});
```

Actually what I want to know is, is the specific element in focus or not!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply check if your `textarea` is `focused` using the jQuery [`:focus`](https://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/) selector :

```
$(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if($('#yourTextarea').is(':focus')){
            //...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yess, that is exactly what I needed